# Get ETH back from smart contract - scam

Tags: ether, scam

I have created a smart contract using a scammed code, with no feature to withdraw funds. However, funds are still on the contract for now 200 days, meaning scammer has not withdraw them yet. Is there any possibility for me, as the contract constructor, to subsequently add a withdrawal function by creating a new smart contract "At address" ? FYI my contract is 0x36c72af71222AF49016caD945DAFD624699595Cf [contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x36c72af71222AF49016caD945DAFD624699595Cf?fbclid=IwAR28xwy3jI-zEo7gn_FlBO9CwDkUhckIbZpgcn4oaVqMocnjzgALXpFVDvM)

I must mention that I am more than a newbie... And really bad even to create a smart contract without step-by-step details...

Many thanks for your help. Louis

Comment: Can you verify the contract source code?

Comment: Unfortunately, code page has been deleted since then. No possibility to find it back

Comment: not possible to answer without seeing the code :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, functionality cannot be modified once a smart contract is deployed on the blockchain.

Since the contract you provided does not have a feature to withdraw funds, there is no way to withdraw the funds from the contract using the contract itself.

Comment: or using anything else!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I gave up already to be honest, but I needed a last confirmation, as it is frustrating to see funds still on the contract...